# Reduce Cordova Chrome App (cca) APK Size

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

I've put together a Chrome App using Polymer and wanted to install it on the Android platform.  I've successfully followed the steps listed here, compiled and deployed an SDK:

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps

The problem, is that my chrome app is only 37k, and the compiled SDK is 37Mb. I tried also compiling down the 'Hello World' sample and got a similar file size.

While I anticipated there would be some overhead this seems remarkably high. I'm assuming it's because the cca command line automatically pulls in all anticipated plugins that you might need, even though I'm probably using very few (if any) of them.

Is there a way to reduce the file size on apps built with cca - or is this just a limitation while it's in its early developer preview stages?

Cheers!

Comment: Are you using the default Cordova splash screens for the app, they're quite big and you often don't need them all (e.g. do you need both Portrait and Landscape splash screens)

Comment: I was just running 'build --release' - I haven't found any documentation describing ways to include or exclude anything. Is it just a case of finding them in the file system and deleting them?

Comment: You know what this was the case in versions earlier than 3, I've just checked a new 3.5.0 project and the files only take up about 2MB, so they are much better optimised now. FYI in the `your-project/platforms/android/res` folder and `your-project/platforms/ios/ProjectName/Resources` folders you can find all the icons and splash screens.

Comment: Can you check the `/www` folder of the Cordova project, see if there are any resources in there that you don't want in the app. Things like .zip files, Photoshop files, anything that you might have left in there when writing your app.

Comment: The www folder has only necessary files - I'd already identified this as a likely suspect and removed some node modules that I'd left in last night but that didn't account for much.

The version is something I'll check, although according to this:

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/releases

It's only on version 0.2.2 - Is CCA in a separate repository somewhere?

Comment: Ignore that last comment - I can see Cordova is a dependency - I'll give it a try when I get home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The large size of Chrome Apps for Mobile (using the `cca` tool) is due to us bundling the [Crosswalk WebView](http://crosswalk-project.org) automatically, which is currently based on Chrome/36.  (This is also an approach we are working hard to get in to cordova-android 4.0 to be release later this year).

At the moment, we build a single apk with support for both intel and arm.  We will soon split up the build into separate apks for each architecture, and thus cut the apk size overhead by half.  We do expect there to be around ~18Mb overhead using this approach for the foreseeable future, though.

If you would really like, you can opt-out of using crosswalk by adding `"webview": "system"` to your `manifest.mobile.json` and rebuilding your project ([but there may be a bug here at the moment](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/215), see issue for workaround).

You can read more information from our [Release Notes](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md#v011-june-25-2014), but we've got on our backlog to write up a whole FAQ about this approach.

You should know that even on the latest Android KitKat 4.4.3, the system webview will not run Polymer components without polyfills.  Most polymer apps run dog slow without the Crosswalk webview (since Chrome/36 is first version to run polymer components natively).

Hope that helps you evaluate your options, and hopefully we can cut the apk size asap.  Best of luck!

Comment: OK thanks, that'll save me some time investigating further! I'll stick with it - with Polymer this is a really interesting platform.

Comment: @mmocny Hey! So is the build split up now? Are you offering different builds for ARM and x86? And one more thing. Does Google play offer a service to upload different APK's for different version (4.1, 4.2, 4.4) of Android devices?

Comment: @SiddharthaRRamesh Yes, we split the apk based on architecture by default now, reducing the size overhead to 17mb.  You can upload multiple apks to the play store, but if you want to customize the android version target, you will need to play games with the apk version number and min SDK version specifications.  We don't do this for you by default.